# Is it possible to resize an embedded .mov?

Tags: html, resize, embed, quicktime, movie

I embed .mov clips that sometimes are bigger than the place where I show it, so I want to resize the clip. Have tried with `width` and `height` but that only changes the area to display it; it does not resize the actual movie.

Is it possible to resize the movie size? If yes, how?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you need the `scale` attribute:

```
<embed src="sample.mov" width="200" height="240" scale="tofit">
```

There's a full reference for QuickTime video attributes [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/TA26485).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the scale attribute doesn't work. It would help to place the embed element in an object element.

```
<object height="240" width="200"><embed src="sample.mov" height="240" width="200"/></object>
```

Make sure that the height and width value in the object element is the same as in the embed element.
      Good Luck