# Resize an embed tag, not crop it

Tags: html, embed

How do I resize an embed tag (like how one can resize an img tag)?

Example:

```
<embed src="1.mp4" width="1280" height="1024" />
```

This works fine because the original is 1280 x 1024.  But if I

```
<embed src="1.mp4" width="640" height="512" />
```

Then it crops the movie rather than sizing it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Is it possible to resize an embedded .mov?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311124/is-it-possible-to-resize-an-embedded-mov)

You need the `scale="tofit"` attribute at the end of your embed tag.

```
<embed src="1.mp4" width="640" height="512" scale="tofit"/>
```

In IE 7, 8 when using Quicktime you should add:

```
<param name="SCALE" VALUE="aspect" >
```

Otherwise the video will be cropped.